# how to update a property value of a jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql-13

I have a jsonb type named attr field that contains the following:

```json
{ 
  "pid": 1,
  "name": "john",
  "is_default": true
 }
```

how to change is_default to false?

I try to run below, but no luck.

```
update attr set attr ->> 'is_default' = false where sales_type = 2
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

Simply concatenating the new key/value pair:

```
update the_table
  set attr = attr || '{"is_default": false}';
```

This works because when concatenating two `jsonb` values, existing keys will be overwritten.

The other way is to use `jsonb_set()` that updates a value at a location specified through a "path" (which is defined through the elements of an array)

```
update the_table
  set attr = jsonb_set(attr, array['is_default'], to_jsonb(false));
```

---

If you're on version 14 (released September 2021) or greater, you can simplify this to:

```
update the_table
   set attr['is_default'] = to_jsonb(false);
```

Comment: In case dealing with text input looks like casting is needed `set attr['is_default'] = to_jsonb('my_text'::text)`

Answer (score 10):

Let's say we got this `jsonb`

```
{
    "animals": [
        {"name": "Cat", "age": 5},
        {"name": "Dog", "age": 10}
    ]
}
```

We want to update the age of `Cat` from 5 to 15. The function `jsonb_set(...)` returns a new jsonb with updated value.

```
select
    jsonb_set(
        '{"animals": [{"name": "Cat", "age": 5}, {"name": "Dog", "age": 10}]}',
        '{animals,0,age}',  -- Path to the field to update
        '15'::jsonb,  -- New value to set
        false  -- If true, this will make a new key if it doesn't exist in the jsonb
    )
;
```

If you would like to do something like that in an SQL update, this would go like;

```
update animals
set
    animals_metadata = jsonb_set(animals_metadata, '{animals,0,age}', to_jsonb(15), false)
where id = '123';
```

Check out the official [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) for more!

Comment: Even though someone downvoted it for no reason, this does work. If someone gets across this, and still isn't satisfied, please comment.